# The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting a **415 Unsupported Media Type** error trying to POST data. The response has ***"The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.*"** although the content-type is set **application/json**.

Does anyone see what's going wrong here?

ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route( @"api/Assignments/{id:int}" )]
public HttpResponseMessage Save( int id, [FromBody] Assignment assignment )
{
    try
    {
        int result = 0;

              .
              .
              .

        return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        //log error
        return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
    }
}
```

Service:

```
service.saveAssignment = function (assignment) {
    var serviceurl = baseURL + "api/Assignments/" + (assignment.ID || 0);
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        data: angular.toJson(assignment),
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8;" },
        url: serviceurl
    });
};
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:31415/api/Assignments/0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:31415
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:31415
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:31415/Settings
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"SemesterID":3,"CourseID":1,"FacultyID":1}
```

Response:

*{"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header.
 The inferred media type **'application/octet-stream'** is not supported for this resource.", "ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Assignment' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.", "ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
"StackTrace":"  at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n  at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}*

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?